# A new piece of clue for document classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am working on a document classification problem. I am using the typical vector space  model to represent a document as doc-term vector. If document has some term, the vector entry for that term is 1.

But with the training data, I can get a piece of information which I think may be useful. It is the term popularity within each category respectively. It is defined as below:

$$
\text{Popularity} (\text{term}\ T, \text{category}\ X) = \frac{\text{documents belonging to}\ X\ \text{containing}\ T}{\text{total documents belonging to}\ X}
$$

This is calculated with the training set.

I believe this value can be interpreted as the **representability** of a term for a certain category, which in other words, is the term's popularity within a certain category.

I have a feeling that it could somehow influence the vector weight for a term. But I haven't figured out a reasonable way to use it. If I want to use this popularity value for a new document to be classified, I need to know its category first (or do I?). This is kind of a dilemma.

Could anyone shed some light? Could this clue be helpful in the classification?

### ADD 1

Here is my first attempt to use this Popularity value.
For each doc to be classified, I make an assumption about its category, and multiply the BIT vector with the term-popularity values for that assumed category. And then, I use some machine learning algorithm to calculate the probability for this doc belong to that assumed category with the new vector. I did this assume-predict for each category. And finally I get a list of probabilities for each category. Then I choose the category with maximum probability as the final prediction.

BUT, the result turns out not as good as I expected. It seems even worse than BIT (I am not 100% sure about this.)

Comment: So... conditional probability?

Comment: @alto, not sure yet. Still thinking about it.

Comment: The formula you've written is the maximum likelihood estimate for $P(T \mid X)$ assuming $T$ and $X$ are a binary and categorical random variable respectively.

Comment: @alto So, if I understand it right, we can interpret P(T|X) as "given X, how possible I will see T". But I am still not sure how to utilize it in classification task.